# Does LibUsb-win32 require every device to have its own INF file?

Tags: python, usb, hid, pyusb, libusb-1.0

I'm trying to develop a USB board that can connect to the computer as a HID device and talk to a Python application I'd write. I want to use Python and I went with a HID device to be driver free.

This seems like a great solution until I ran into lilbusb-win32. After working with it for a bit it looks like I have to create an INF file for my USB device. I've read that the INF recognizes the USB device's IDs (VID and PID). Wouldn't this mean every single device would need to ship with its own INF file basically negating the idea of being driver free with HID in the first place?

Would Libusb-win32 and PyUsb allow me to create a program to talk to any board as long as they were all the same HID devices (just having different product id's)? If so, do users need to download the INF with my program?

This seems to defeat the purpose of going with HID in the first place.

Comment: Afaik, you'll need to tell `libusb-win32` which devices to "take over", since otherwise it'd have no choice but to take over _every_ newly connected USB device that does not have a built-in driver.

Comment: So with the same pid and vid would it be possible to pack up a python app. With pyusb and libusb-win32 and have all of these modules and dependancies in one package so the user doesn't have to download anything manually other than this package?